# VB: How to send email with SMTP... Dynamically set host and port for major ISP's

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I am working on a VB application that sends an HTML email. I found this, and am trying to implement it.

```
 'create the mail message
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()

            'set the addresses
            mail.From = New MailAddress(EmailFrom, "Display Name")
            mail.To.Add(EmailTo)

            'set the content
            mail.Subject = "Subject Line"
            mail.Body = "Message body"
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True

            'send the message
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("127.0.0.1")
            smtp.Send(mail)
```

I don't have any info on the argument passed to SmtpClient() for this code snippet.

I have found videos showing how to connect to google smtp using "smtp.gmail.com" and a specific port. However, This would only be practical if all of the users of my application will have Gmail. I don't want to force them to have one in order to have access to the functionality.

Could any of you experts provide me with some help on dynamically selecting the correct smtp server and port based on their email?

for example, email is stored in a variable called email:

```
Dim email As String = "me@gmail.com"
```

This email is coming from MySql database so how do I take variable string and check which ISP they use and then have my code use the correct smtp and port for that ISP?

Also, I've read that now days authentication is required so I will likely prompt user with input box before calling procedure that sends the email.

Here's some code showing that:

Hotmail:
Smtp.live.com
Port: 587

Gmail:
smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587

Yahoo:
smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Port: 465

Aol:
smtp.aol.co.uk

### Port: 587

```
imports system.net.mail

dim Mail as new mailmessage
Try
mail.From = New MailAddress("FROM EMAIL")
mail.To.Add(TO EMAIL)
mail.Subject = "SUBJECT"
mail.Body = "BODY"
Dim s As New SmtpClient("HOST")
s.Port = PORT
s.EnableSsl = True
s.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("FROM EMAIL, "FROM PASSWORD")
s.Send(Mail)
MsgBox("E-mail was sucsessfully sent!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

I'm completely stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also open to any ideas that accomplish same feat even if not in accordance with first code snippet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need more than just an IP and a port. Some mail servers require various methods and measures of encryption, authentication, anti-spam, etc. You are not taking on a trivial task, that's for sure! You will likely need to build and maintain a database of SMTP server settings with e-mail domains. If you're only supporting the "major" ones you might not have that much work, but keep in mind there are potentially millions of e-mail providers out there.

Comment: Why is your smtp client your local port?

Comment: The local port was included in that code snippet when I found it.

Comment: I'm only gonna target major ISP's. I know I need To Address, From Address, subject, body, port and credentials. Is there more? How can I compare a string such as me@gmail.com in VB to detect the characters after the @?

Comment: Which one are you going to target first? Let's get that one out of the way and then worry about the rest.

Comment: Let's look at Gmail first. But, Would we not have to go back and use code to dynamically detect the ISP and then find the host server and port in database to then fill basic smtp email sub? I can get one to work, gmail for example, but if the user does not have gmail the host and port would fail authentication.

Comment: I think one problem is with the `mail.To.Add(TO EMAIL)` part, remove the `TO` next for gmail you need to active it so you can use 3rd party "email clients" follow the two links 1st - https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity Fill out all your details.

2nd - switch this on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Maybe this would help me solve it. If I have a string such as "me@gmail.com" is there a native function that can begin after @ and split the string? If I can use a function like that to grab the ISP, then the rest would be easy to figure out on my own. Either way, I will share the final result here.

Comment: before jumping the gun, have you managed to send an email?

Comment: @DavidG: Look at `String.IndexOf` and `String.Substring`.

Comment: @ Corey... I have not but will look into it now. I also just found this webpage which has an exact example. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Corey yes i beleive string.indexof and string.substring methods will be exactly what i need to compare to database to get host and port info Thanks